# How to make a 4 point path follow an object at either end? (How to make a fake node graph)?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I am trying to simulate a node graph like [this](https://www.usenodl.dev/) where a path with 4 points (start, 2 middle, end) adapts to the movement of an object connected to the start and end:

[image]

If you move a node at the link above you can see this demonstrated. So far I've followed [this tutorial using a beam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NZCj8vVZZM) but this is 2 points - not 4 - with no support for curved paths.

How can I simulate this node graph effect?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one to do without plugins.  I've used [ConnectLayersPro](https://aescripts.com/connect-layers/) to achieve this kind of thing, with the curves set to Step mode:

[image]

If anyone knows how to do it using expressions (and maybe the built in Beam plugin?) I'd love to know.